# segmentation fault after calling a toString function twice

Tags: c++, class, tree, segmentation-fault

I am currently working on writing a left-child right sibling class. My addSibling function and my toString function is not working as intended. I wish to order the siblings in ascending ASCII values and let my addSibling function return false when the character inside the root is a duplicate.
My header file has a class CTree that has public member data,kids,sibs,prev and the function declarations. The weird thing is when I create a test and try to output a root with its child,

```
CTree* t1 = new CTree('A') ;
    assert(t1->toString() == string("A\n"));

    // A
    // |
    // b
    assert(t1->addChild('b'));


    cout<<t1->toString();
    cout<<t1->toString();
```

This gives me an segmentation fault

My cpp file:

```
using std::string;

CTree::CTree(char ch)
  :data(ch),kids(nullptr),sibs(nullptr),prev(nullptr){
}

CTree::~CTree(){
  if(kids!=NULL){
    delete kids;
  }
  if(sibs!=NULL){
    delete sibs;
  }
}

bool CTree::addChild(char ch){
  //if there is a kid, add ch as the sib of the kid
    if (kids){
      if (kids->data==ch){
        return false;
      }

      bool temp=kids->addSibling(ch);
      return temp;
    }
    else{
    //if there is not a kid, create CTree ch that is the child of this
      CTree temp(ch);
      kids=&temp;
      return true;
    }
}
bool CTree::addSibling(char ch){
  //create a CTree, and call addSibling with &CTree
    CTree temp(ch);
    return this->addSibling(&temp);
}


bool CTree::addSibling(CTree *root){
  //initialize prev
    prev=this;
    //loop over sibs in a recursive fashion, and comparing the values
    while (sibs){
      //if the char in sib and root is the same return false
      if (sibs->data==root->data){
          return false;
        }
      //if the char in sib is smaller than root then continue moving forward
      else if((sibs->data)<(root->data)){
          prev=sibs;
          sibs=sibs->sibs;
      }
      //when the char in sib is bigger than the root, put root as the sib of prev
      else {
          prev->sibs=root;
          return true;
      }
//if sib points to null and there exist no sib that is bigger than the root, put root as the last sib

    if (prev->data==root->data){
      return false;
    }
    else{
    prev->sibs=root;
    return true;
    }
}


string CTree::toString(){
  if(kids!=nullptr){
    return string(1,this->data)+"\n"+kids->toString();
  }
  else{
    return string(1,this->data)+"\n";
  }
  if(sibs!=nullptr){
    return string(1,this->data)+"\n"+sibs->toString();
  }
  else{
    return string(1,this->data)+"\n";
  }
}
```

I really dont understand where the seg fault is coming from, I didnt free any memory inside my toString function!

Comment: You need to allocate memory inside addChild. If you take the address of a local variable, you will have a dangling pointer.

Comment: One more thing I would do is make the `toString` method `const` to help catch accidental modifications.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines from the `addSibling` function are what leads to your problem:

```
CTree temp(ch);
return this->addSibling(&temp);
```

The first line defines a *local* variable inside the `addSibling` function. The life-time of this variable ends when the function returns, and the object is destructed.

The second line call will save a pointer to this local variable, a pointer that will become invalid as soon as `addSibling` returns.

Attempting to dereference this pointer later will lead to *undefined behavior*.

A possible solution is to allocate `temp` dynamically

```
CTree* temp = new CTree(ch);
return this->addSibling(temp);  // Note lack of address-of operator & here
```

You have the same problem in `addChild` with the lines

```
CTree temp(ch);
kids=&temp;
```

Here you need to do e.g.:

```
kids = new CTree(ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `AddChild`, you are doing this:

```
CTree temp(ch);
kids = &temp;
```

but `temp` is a local variable, so as soon as you return from this function, it dies, and `kids` is no longer pointing to a valid object.

Instead, you need to do something like this:

```
kids = new Ctree(ch);
```

You need to fix all your functions where you are doing a similar thing.